# In Drupal administration page, when I click on the configuration link and report status link it shows empty page in production environment

Tags: drupal-7

**Drupal Administration:**
After enter into the drupal administration, when I click on the configuration link and status report link it shows empty page in production environment.

**Note:** In Local environment it works fine.

So please guide me how to fix this issue?

Comment: What if you simply open http://yourproductionsite/admin ?

Comment: [mysite/admin](http://example.com/admin/) - It's working fine.  [mysite/admin/config](http://example.com/admin/config) - This URL shows an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

Sìnce you say same drupal enviroment works fine in development and is failing in production, I would try and update the .htaccess file from development to production.

Comment: What i have to do with .htaccess file. I am also increased the execution time, memory limit, max input vars, max input time and post max size. Still I am facing the empty page issue while access the administration configuration link, status report link and available updates link. Please give your suggestions.